# Big letter with text flowing around it

Tags: html, css

I have some text that I want to format so that the first letter to be big. The text looks like this without CSS:

```html
<p>
  <span>V</span>estibulum et arcu sodales dolor sagittis sollicitudin. Pellentesque vitae eros nec lacus iaculis viverra. Maecenas vitae sapien et augue tincidunt elementum. Pellentesque velit. Mauris eget tellus. Proin ultricies scelerisque magna. Sed
  pretium tempor mi. Aenean vel lacus. Cras quam. Ut faucibus enim sed mauris. Morbi malesuada nunc eu arcu. Integer quam. Quisque ac nunc. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nulla ac mi sit amet ante aliquet euismod. Ut suscipit.
  In turpis. In at diam nec elit malesuada venenatis. In nec leo nec est ullamcorper nonummy. Suspendisse in nisl. Nam dolor. Nunc
</p>
```

If I just set the `font-size` of `span` bigger than the paragraph's, the letter does get bigger, but the next letter starts at the bottom right. I need to have the next letter start at the top right, and the paragraph's lines to flow around the big letter. I have tried using vertical inline but can't seem to manage to get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `float: left;` in the CSS that affects the first letter should make the remaining text wrap around it.

As a side note, you can just use the `::first-letter` pseudo element to affect the first letter of an element.

For example, to the first letter of each `<p>`:

```
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 130%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: I can't use first letter. I use the same identifier multiple times so I would have to change a lot to just use first-letter. If I just use float: left; The letter still start at the bottom right and not top right.

Comment: In the case, applying the `float: left;` to the span should still do trick. Just keep in mind that `::first-letter` exists for the next time you want to do this kind of design :)

Comment: No problem! Play around with the padding values, that should give it the right look. See this example fiddle forked from yours: http://jsfiddle.net/pv2xvad2/

Answer (score 3):

is that what you need ?

```css
  p:first-letter {
    float: left;
    font-size: 5em;
    line-height: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.05em;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
  }
```

```html
<p>Vestibulum et arcu sodales dolor sagittis sollicitudin. Pellentesque vitae eros nec lacus iaculis viverra. Maecenas vitae sapien et augue tincidunt elementum. Pellentesque velit. Mauris eget tellus. Proin ultricies scelerisque magna. Sed pretium tempor
  mi. Aenean vel lacus. Cras quam. Ut faucibus enim sed mauris. Morbi malesuada nunc eu arcu. Integer quam. Quisque ac nunc. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nulla ac mi sit amet ante aliquet euismod. Ut suscipit. In turpis. In
  at diam nec elit malesuada venenatis. In nec leo nec est ullamcorper nonummy. Suspendisse in nisl. Nam dolor. Nunc</p>
```